# PythonAnywhere, Flask application, heroku postgres psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2, pythonanywhere

i am trying to connect a very simple Flask app with a db hosted on heroku but whatever i do i get a connection refused error.

### flask_app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/weapons', methods=['GET'])
def api_all():
    DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://'user':'password'@ec2-34-246-24-110.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/'db_name''

    conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    all_weapons = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM weapons;').fetchall()

    return jsonify(all_weapons)
```

where 'user', 'password' and 'db_name' are the ones heroku gave me.

### Pythonanywhere Error Log:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
#011Is the server running on host "ec2-34-246-24-110.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (34.246.24.110) and accepting
#011TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
NO MATCH
```

Comment: Is it free or paid account? Free accounts have limited internet access.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change line with SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to following

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```